# c++ smart pointer c'tor design explaination

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

When I read the code:

```cpp
    DefaultSPStorage() : pointee_(Default()) {}

    DefaultSPStorage(const DefaultSPStorage&) : pointee_(nullptr) {}

    template<class U>
    DefaultSPStorage(const DefaultSPStorage<U>) : pointee_(nullptr) {}

    explicit DefaultSPStorage(const StoredType& p) : pointee_(p) {}
```

I feel confused on the third templated c'tor.

If anyone can enlighten me the purpose of it, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. However, the third constructor looks like a conversion constructor (could be used with another smart pointer holding any pointee). However, none of both copy constructors seem to copy anything. This is what I would feel confused about. If copy construction is not intended, I would delete these constructors to prevent accidental usage... (But, maybe, it's just too less context to justify this.)

Comment: You should provide at least the class declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DefaultSPStorage()` is a template class, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class DefaultSPStorage
{
    ...
};
```

The third templated constructor takes a `DefaultSPStorage<U>` instance whose template parameter can be different than the `DefaultSPStorage` instance that is being constructed.

IOW, this allows constructing a `DefaultSPStorage<A>` using a `DefaultSPStorage<B>` as input, eg:

```cpp
DefaultSPStorage<short> a;
DefaultSPStorage<int> b(a);
```

Comment: That's right, but furthermore, can you please also enlighten me some use cases of this template c'tor

Comment: @Edee Take `std::unique_ptr`, for example. It has a template constructor, which allows a `std::unique_ptr<T>` to be constructed from (ie, transfer ownership from) another `std::unique_ptr<U>`, where `U` derives from `T` and thus `U*` is implicitly convertible to `T*`